# How to generate random while uploading multiple images

Tags: php

I am trying to generate random name while uploading multiple images. I have already done this while uploading single images and also the image size is  compressed after image is uploaded. I am trying to do same while uploading multiple images.

Here is my code which is uploading multiple images but with same name,

```
$birtimage=$_FILES['birtimage']['name'];     
$birtimage = implode(",",$birtimage);
$pic = "upload/"; 
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['birtimage']['name']);$i++){
$target_file = $pic.basename($_FILES["birtimage"]["name"][$i]);
$imageFiletype= pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["birtimage"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file))
  {
    $msg="The file has been successfully uploaded"; 
  } 
  else{
    $msg="not found image";
  } 
}
```

Here is my code that works perfect for single images,

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['bday_banner'] ['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $bday_banner = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension;
    $location = "assets/birthday/banner/".$bday_banner;

    if(in_array(strtolower($extension), [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ])){
        compressImage($_FILES['bday_banner']['tmp_name'],$location,60);
    }else{
        echo "Invalid file type.";
    }
```

Also here is the function that compress my images while uploading single image,

```
 function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {

            $info = getimagesize($source);

            if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

            elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

            imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

        }
```

I have tried this :

```
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['birtimage'] ['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $birtimage = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension;
    $birtimage = implode(",",$birtimage);
    $location = "upload/".$birtimage;
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['birtimage']['name']);$i++){

    if(in_array(strtolower($extension), [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ])){
        compressImage($_FILES['birtimage']['tmp_name'][$i],$location,60);
    }else{
        echo "Invalid file type.";
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [name] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; Ammy.jpg
            [1] =&gt; banner1.jpg
            [2] =&gt; banner2.jpg
            [3] =&gt; banner4.jpg
        )

    [type] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; image/jpeg
            [1] =&gt; image/jpeg
            [2] =&gt; image/jpeg
            [3] =&gt; image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; D:\xampp\tmp\phpBAA2.tmp
            [1] =&gt; D:\xampp\tmp\phpBAA3.tmp
            [2] =&gt; D:\xampp\tmp\phpBAA4.tmp
            [3] =&gt; D:\xampp\tmp\phpBAB4.tmp
        )

    [error] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; 0
            [1] =&gt; 0
            [2] =&gt; 0
            [3] =&gt; 0
        )

    [size] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; 19860
            [1] =&gt; 553916
            [2] =&gt; 476609
            [3] =&gt; 515885
        )

)
```

updated :

```
$birtimages = $_FILES['birtimage'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($birtimages); $i++) {
    $extension = pathinfo($birtimages[$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $birtimages = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension;
    $location = "upload/".$birtimages;

    if (in_array(strtolower($extension), [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ])) {
        compressImage($birtimages[$i]['tmp_name'], $location, 60);
    } else {
        //echo "Invalid file type.";
        // do what you want to trap error with or without exiting the loop
    }
```

Comment: You could use the same exact single image code in the for loop of the multiple images code

Comment: i have tried but i am stuck near $birtimage = implode(",",$birtimage);

Comment: So the problem is not in the generating random name, but in the getting post files.

Comment: i have tried something like that, please check above update code

Comment: you have to explain exactly whats your problem right now, and when (in which line) happens

Comment: showing error  :  pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, on line  $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['birtimage'] ['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: and showing error   :  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in   on line   $birtimage = implode(",",$birtimage);

Comment: these are two errors

Answer (score 0):

For that please use this code inside the foreach loop

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

Here microtime(true) will create the random number.
We will firstly fetch the file extension whether jpg or png etc.

Then after we will rename that file by joining that to the random number
even you could concat the original file name with the random number

It's a good idea to generate the names so as to prevent the duplicates.

Comment: can you please share full code, i am not getting this

Answer (score 0):

A safer way to generate random filenames is to use the PHP [tempnam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) function.

> Creates a file with a unique filename, with access permission set to
>   0600, in the specified directory. If the directory does not exist or
>   is not writable, tempnam() may generate a file in the system's
>   temporary directory, and return the full path to that file, including
>   its name.

#### Example:

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/path_to_file");
```

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: At the moment you generate a random number as the file name. There is a chance that the generated number already exists. So that's why your method is not safe to use since you can overwrite an existing file. If you use `tempnam()`, an unique file name is generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is also in the html.
In the html you should have something like this:

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="birtimage[]" multiple><br>
    <input type="file" name="birtimage[]" multiple><br>
    <input type="file" name="birtimage[]" multiple><br>
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD">
</form>
```

Then in the PHP file you can do:

```
if (isset($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['birtimage'])) {
    $birtimages = $_FILES['birtimage'];
    $pic = "upload/";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($birtimages['name']); $i++) {
        $extension = pathinfo($birtimages['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $bday_banner = rand(10000,99999) . '.' . $extension;
        $location = "assets/birthday/banner/".$bday_banner;

        if (in_array(strtolower($extension), [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ])) {
            compressImage($birtimages['tmp_name'][$i], $location, 60);
        } else {
            //echo "Invalid file type.";
            // do what you want to trap error with or without exiting the loop
        }
    }
}
```

I tried and this code worked for me, without any errors.

Comment: i am using this  <input type="file" name="birtimage[]" multiple>

Comment: again write error you get. telling "still not working" does not help

Comment: showing errors  :  Undefined offset: 0 in line    $extension = pathinfo($birtimages[$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: try this: echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES['birtimage']); and write what you get

Comment: i am getting something like above ' in output section '

Comment: you are using target twice, please check my updated section

Comment: you have to invert "name" and $i to access the array values. I edited the code for that

Comment: still not working showing errors on   :  Illegal string offset 'tmp_name' in  line  compressImage($birtimages['tmp_name'][$i], $location, 60);  and also some errors in compressor function but the same compressor is working fine with single image upload

Comment: same errors and in "for" code too showing error  :  Illegal string offset 'name' in

Comment: i edited the code. I tried it and it worked without any errors. If you get error it occurs somewhere else

Comment: why are you using two file paths i.e.   $pic = "upload/";    and  also  $location = "assets/birthday/banner/".$bday_banner;

Comment: I copied your code, it does not matter what path you use.

Comment: still not working dude, i don't understand how it is working in your case